# I want to add default text in blogger comment box on my website

Tags: javascript, html

Can anyone suggest me to improve my code. By which i can add a default text in my comment box. Please help me. Thank you in advance.

```
<a href='http://www.blogger.com/comment-iframe.g?blogID=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&amp;postID=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX' id='comment-editor-src' title='comment editor'>
</a>
<iframe class='blogger-iframe-colorize blogger-comment-from-post' height='410' id='comment-editor' name='comment-editor'>
</iframe>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.blogger.com/static/v1/jsbin/2875839671-comment_from_post_iframe.js">
</script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
      BLOG_CMT_createIframe('https://www.blogger.com/rpc_relay.html', 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX');
</script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
      //<![CDATA[
      if (typeof(jQuery) == 'undefined') {
 //output the script (load it from google api)
 document.write("<scr" + "ipt type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js\">
</scr" + "ipt>");}
        //]]>
       </script>
<script async='async' src='//www.blogblog.com/dynamicviews/4224c15c4e7c9321/js/comments.js' type='text/javascript'>
</script>
```

Comment: Could you be a little more specific as to what you would like to accomplish?

Comment: you can use the placeholder property to input or textarea element to show the default text example <textarea placeholder="Writer you comment here."></textarea>

Comment: @Ignatius_Gim sir, I would like to give suggestion to user.

Comment: @KeyurPatel You can use placeholders

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use code below:

```
var $iframe = $('#comment-editor');
$iframe.ready(function() {
 $iframe.contents().find("body").append('Test');
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Văn Tuấn Phạm

Comment: Sir it's not working. Can you give me more suggestion.

Comment: Is it possible to do it without jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be to use in your `iframe` a `textarea` with a your default message within property `placeholder`.

```html
<textarea placeholder="Your default message."></textarea>
```

> The placeholder attribute specifies a short hint that describes the
>   expected value of a text area.
>   The short hint is displayed in the text area before the user enters a
>   value.

Comment: Sir, it's not working can you help me out to find out a solution.

Comment: @KeyurPatel please provide more information, what is not working? Do you have an error? Do you have a link to show us? Thanks